# How to find from where a table is updated

Tags: ms-access, reverse-engineering

I am reverse engineering an ms-Access application and there is a table, for which I cannot find the Update statement. So I cannot find the form or query from where it is updated. Is there a way to search in Access's meta data?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that underneath the covers Access does not use SQL to update the table. While you can export all objects as text this would NOT solve your issue since what happens in code such as:

strTable = Inputbox("What table to Modify?")

strSql = "update " & strTable & " blab la bla"

So in a typical application not all code uses SQL and worse some of it will be REAL code and NOT hard coded. At the end of the day just keep in mind the HUGE limitations of your question.

However Access does have a built in “dependency” feature. The result is a VERY nice tree-view of those dependencies, and you can even launch such objects using that treeview of your application to “navigate” the application so to speak.

The option is found under database tools and is appropriately called Object Dependencies.

The result looks like this:

[image]
While I do NOT use track name auto correct, few often realize that you can turn on auto track, but turn off track name correct (so I recommend one do this else edits to objects will cause automatic updates to those dependencies).

Also note if auto correct data not been indexed, then on a large application the FIRST time this option is used can result in a “considerable” delay as every single reference and object is indexed. After the first use then use of this option is near instant due to the data being indexed.

Note that the option gives “both” ways – objects that depend on me and objects that “I” depend on.

A brilliant built in feature that I wish other developer tools had built in like Access does. This feature I believe requires 2010 or later.